# Create a slider with stripes effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a slider with stripes effect like in the image below:

[image]

How do they "cut" the image in a number of stripes? *I would like "cut" my image in **custom shape stripes** (not the default rectangular ones like in the example, but curved in a custom manner).*

Link to the actual example slider: http://www.jssor.com/demos/x-stripe.html

**I just need the conceptual explanation, the starting point, I don't expect or want the actual code.** I searched on the internet but the tutorials only reffer to simple effects as sliding or fading which I know how to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this done a couple of places ...

The general idea for these effects, is to create a series of elements that align the image within them to the appropriate part of the transitioning image.

This could be done a couple of ways. Either using background-image settings in css. or putting img elements inside each strip, and setting the positioning to absolute and the left to a negative offset matching the strips position. you then animate the strips. Once the animation is complete, remove all the strips and replace with the original image.

hopefully this points you in the right direction. Let me know if it doesn't make sense.

as for curved cuts - this could be a bit tricker to pull off with html/javascript ... however you could possibly use border-radius to cut the corners of the strips. doing so with large numbers - eg 100px radius, you could possibly pull off circles.

another alternative perhaps would be using SVGs with background images - but i haven't tried mixing those together - you'd need to look into that.